# Writing asynchronous task that manipulates a never-expiring list (in Django)

Tags: django, memcached

In a Django project I maintain, users upload photos for others to see and comment on. I don't want anyone to upload recently seen photos, so I compare every photo being uploaded to the most recent 300 photos. If I find duplication, I remind the user to try something new. I want to optimize this process - that's what this question is about.

Currently, whenever a user tries to upload a photo, this code is processed from inside the `form_valid` method of the class based view responsible for photo uploading:

```
recent_photos = Photo.objects.order_by('-id')[:300]
recent_hashes = [photo.avg_hash for photo in recent_photos]
#some code to compare avg_hash values across images to flag duplication
```

Instead of making this DB call from the client every time a user uploads a photo, I want maintain a list of the most recent 300 avg hash values of every image *in the cache*. This way, I eliminate the DB call.

Now the average_hash value for each image is saved in the DB at the time of `photo` object creation. I want to write an asynchronous task that essentially receives the avg_hash value for every image, and inserts it into a list of cached avg_hash values, maintaining the list at 300 length and infinite expiry time.

Can someone help me with programming such a task? I'm thinking it ought to be something like:

```
@celery_app1.task(name='tasks.build_avg_hash_list')
def build_avg_has_list(latest_avg_hash):
    cache_mem = get_cache('django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache', **{
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211', 'TIMEOUT': None,
    })
    try:    
        avg_hash_list = cache_mem.get('avg_hash_list')
        avg_hash_list.insert(0,latest_avg_hash)
        list_len = len(avg_hash_list)
        if list_len > 300:
            del avg_hash_list[301:list_len] 
    except:
        avg_hash_list = [latest_avg_hash]
    cache_mem.set('avg_hash_list', avg_hash_list)
```

I'm missing a few things here. For example:

1) I'm using Django 1.5.1, and `Timeout:NONE` doesn't work when setting infinite expiry time.

2) I'm unsure whether my proposed logic reliably fixes the list length at 300 entries or below. Should I be using the `MAX_ENTRIES` cache argument instead?

3) Lastly, : I'm using `cache_mem = get_cache('django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache', **{ 'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211', 'TIMEOUT': 120 })` for one other asynchronous task too. I want to confirm that saving this new task's output in the same location won't *overwrite the output* of the other asynchronous task (which is also saved in the same location).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what is the issue ? Your code is not working, you're getting error? or You want new logic to implement all this process?

Comment: According to your logic, i want to know what kind of exception you are expecting on line 12 (except : )?

Comment: @VikasVerma: The exception where `avg_hash_list = cache_mem.get('avg_hash_list')` fails (e.g. server was restarted and cached items were lost).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at this question and having seen some of your other questions, it's high time that you invest in redis. This seemingly complex task is really simple if you use [redis sets](http://redis.io/commands#set).

Each time some one adds a new image you [add a new entry](https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#redis.StrictRedis.sadd) to your redis set of avg_hashes. You don't even need to limit yourself to 300, you can have thousands of items in the set and since they are peristed on disk, a server restart does not result in data loss.

When you want to see if the user is uploading a duplicate, you call [sismember](https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#redis.StrictRedis.sismember)

If you do want to limit the number of members in the set, you can use srem to clear it up when the length exceeds some previously chosen number.

bonus feature: You don't need the celery task if you adapt redis, but since you are already using celery you may already have redis installed since it's one of celery's supported brokers.

Comment: I do believe that you will overwrite in fact. But this is one of the many issues that you will  be avoiding wtih redis

Comment: Glad to have been of help

Comment: One requirement that isn't fulfilled is that sets are unordered. So if it exceeds the size limit of 300 items, and I want to pop one, the pop would be a random object, instead of *the oldest member* - which is what I need. Any way to circumvent that?

Comment: fortunately there is a sorted set. The commands are very similar except that you need to specify a value for which the primary key can be used http://redis.io/commands#sorted_set